# Magento2: Load product specifying store

Tags: magento2, product, store-view

I have a multi store view with different languages ​​to describe the product. Each store has a different locale defined.

I have this code

```
    $shops = $this->_storeManager->getStores();

    $store_locales = array();
    foreach ($shops as $shop){

        $store_locales[$shop->getName()] = array();
        $store_locales[$shop->getName()][] = $shop->getId();
        $store_locales[$shop->getName()][] = $this->_scopeconfig->getValue('general/locale/code', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $shop->getId());

    }
```

and now i need to load a product desciption specifying a store id.

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Complete untested (sorry!). But as long as you have the product ID you should be able to use the `getAttributeRawValue` function on the resource model.

```
class YourClass {
   protected $product;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
   ) {
       $this->product = $product;
   }

   public function getDescription($productId, $store)
   {
       return $this->product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'description', $store);
   }
}
```

If you're happy to load the full product model then do the following instead.

```
class YourClass {
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getProduct($id, $storeId) {
        return $this->productRepository->getById($id, false, $storeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but you know a way to load the entire object model? Thanks!! (depends store)

Comment: Do you defintiely need the whole model? If it's just to get more attribute values, you can pass an array of attributes into the second parameter.

Comment: is there a list of attributes i can obtain?

Comment: I don't think you'll be restricted. Is there something you can't get?

Comment: i need de price without taxes and with taxes

Comment: I've added an example of how you can get the full product using the productRepository instead if you prefer.